# JavaScript object indexing - many values to one key

Tags: javascript

The problem: In my script I have to generate the same piece of code several items. I wish to use a dictionary to store the key:value pairs and iterate through them. Each key has multiple values associated.

```
let obj = {
    key1: ["val1", "val2", "val3"],
    key2: ["val4", "val5", "val6"]};
```

In my script I want to use the individual values like this:

```
//Key1
some code ${val1}
some other code ${val2}
....
//Key2
some code ${val4}
some other code ${val5}
....
```

I can't find a way to access the individual values instead of the array associated with the key. I've tried 'indexing' ${obj[key][0] but that of course doesn't work.

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key, index) => {
    console.log(`Log the key here: ${obj[key]}!`)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be.

So with Object.entries we get key and value from an object, iterate and get the values.

```js
let obj = {
    key1: ["val1", "val2", "val3"],
    key2: ["val4", "val5", "val6"]
};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, values]) => {
  values.forEach((value) => {
      console.log(`some code ${key}:${value}`)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For iterating through all the values you can do something like this.

---

`for..in loop` for iterating the **object** and

`for..of loop` for iterating the **array** associated with each key of the object

```js
let obj = {
  key1: ["val1", "val2", "val3"],
  key2: ["val4", "val5", "val6"]};


  for(const x in obj){
     for(const y of obj[x]) {
      console.log(`Log the key here: ${y}!`)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank You! Not exactly, what I was looking for but this is a good workaround for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to index in to obj you define in your example, here's how you can pull out 'val1' and 'val2' values.

```js
let obj = {
    key1: ["val1", "val2", "val3"],
    key2: ["val4", "val5", "val6"]};

var v1 = obj['key1'][0];
var v2 = obj['key1'][1];

console.log(v1);
console.log(v2);
```